# Batch for loop with 7zip and variables

Tags: variables, batch-file, 7zip

Why does this:

```
FOR /R "C:\ResultsUnzipping\4\1" %%I IN (*.gz) DO  @ECHO.7z "%I" -aou -o"C:\ResultsUnzipped\%%~nI"
```

in a batch file.

Echo this:

> C:\Users\user\Documents\ResultsFixing>FOR /R "C:\ResultsUnzipping\4\1" %I
>    IN (*.gz) DO @ECHO.7z **"\ResultsUnzipped\%~nI"**
>   7z "\ResultsUnzipped\Wait-3-mins_results.log"
>   7z "\ResultsUnzipped\log-15-mins_results.log"

Why is it chopping off the C:\?

Answer (score 0):

```
FOR /R "C:\ResultsUnzipping" %%I IN (*.gz) DO 7z e "%%I" -aou -o"C:\ResultsUnzipped\%%I"
```

Notice the second % that was missing.